# Is it possible to make one rule take precedence over another in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Say I've got 5 folders in Outlook: one for the four people on my team, and a folder for the team itself.

I've got a rule that when an email comes from any one person on my team it moves from my Inbox to their respective folder. I've got another rule that whenever an email is sent to the Team, it'll get moved to the Team folder. Simple enough.

What happens though is when one person sends an email to whole team, I get 2 emails-- one in the appropriate 'person' folder, and one in the team folder. Is there way to make the "team rule" take precedence over the individual person rule?

Comment: Does ordering the team rule first and telling outlook to stop processing more rules do what you want? (I would have thought that moving the email would prevent other rules on the inbox from firing for that email already but maybe not.)

Comment: Oh, huh, I never even knew there was an option to not process other rules. I'll report back next time a teammate sends an email to the team but I'm pretty sure this should do it.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeap, that solved my issue.